# Analysis Services Tabular File won't open in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssas

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community with SQL Analysis Services 2016 ( 14.0.608.142) installed. If I create a brand new Analysis Services Tabular Project it creates a Model.bim file automatically, but I can't open it. I get a messagebox with:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: contentType

I've checked the debug logs for VS and nothing indicates any failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full uninstall and re-install solved this.